# What causes periodic database errors while using logging, and what should I do about it?

Tags: mysql, logs, db-logging, mysql-archive-format

Running a Drupal site with CiviCRM Logging enabled.  It seems like once a month we get a crash. On investigation one of the log tables is corrupted. Since the tables are type Archive MYSQL provides very limited tools.

The normal fix is to remove the data from the sick table or completely deleting the sick table and rebuilding. Any suggestions for preventing the issue or recovering from the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few orgs who use logging on fairly high volume sites have modified the logging tables to either use MyISAM or InnoDB and have had fairly good success with it. Can you please report back if you adopt this approach and your success with it

Answer (score 0):

Lobo, took your suggestion and converted to InnoDB. We were getting hit with about on failure a month. It has been about 3 weeks, we have not seen a problem. We moved the server to a solid state drive a number of months ago to improve reliability and response time. I don't have any statistics on performance but in general the online system does not write huge amounts of data to the log except when doing a batch operation like a mass mailing,

I would suggest making all new CiviCrm installations use InnoDB to improve reliability which is often much more important then time to log updates.